# Laravel 5.4: No obtengo data de relaciones Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Usando Laravel (con MySQL) Estoy empezando con las relaciones de Eloquent. Intento obtener la data relacionada pero no obtengo nada. Mi configuración es la siguiente:

**Migración proveedores:**

```
Schema::create('proveedores', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('razon_social')->unique();
            $table->string('ruc')->unique();
            $table->integer('id_rubro')->unsigned();
            $table->string('telf_contacto');
            $table->foreign('id_rubro')->references('id')->on('rubros')
                    ->onDelete('cascade')
                    ->onUpdate('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

**Migración rubros:**

```
Schema::create('rubros', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('nombre')->unique();
            $table->string('descripcion')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

**Modelo proveedor:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Proveedor extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;
    protected $table = "proveedores";
    protected $hidden = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'estado'];

    public function rubro(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Rubro');
    }
}
```

**Modelo Rubro:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;

class Rubro extends Model
{
    use SoftDeletes;

    public function proveedores(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Proveedor');
    }
}
```

**Controlador ProveedorController.php**

```
$rubro = Proveedor::find(1);
dd($rubro);
```

**Postman** me devuelve una serie de resultados, pero no veo por ningún lado el bendito **rubro**. ***Qué debería hacer?***

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando defines las relaciones en Eloquent, por defecto en `belongsTo` intentará utilizar como llave foránea el nombre de la relación y agregando la cadena `_id`, lo cual en este caso no se cumple, por lo cual debes definir las llaves foráneas como segundo parámetro en el método de la relación:

```
public function rubro(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Rubro', 'id_rubro');
}
```

Cuando corrijas este pequeño error, deberías poder acceder a la relación o al rubro con las propiedades dinámicas.

Digamos que la manera más semántica sería así:

```
$proveedor = Proveedor::find(1);
$rubro = $proveedor->rubro;
dd($rubro);
```

Lo único "malo" que tiene este método es que estás realizando dos consultas a la base de datos para obtener el rubro. Si quieres realizar solo una consulta y tener el rubro precargado cuando llamas al proveedor, puedes utilizar Eager Loading:

```
$proveedor = Proveedor::with('rubro')->find(1);
dd($proveedor->rubro);
```

Más información en la documentación de Laravel:

- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many
- https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Con tu ayuda funcionó, no sabía eso de las llaves foráneas. Ahora ya tengo lo que necesitaba, seguiré revisando más. Un abrazo y muchas gracias.